# Where is the source in the Zohar that the neshomo of a person or righteous person comes down to the guf on the day of the yorzeit

Tags: soul, zohar

I've heard it quoted, but I don't remember the exact source.

Comment: What would be the purpose of the neshomo coming down to the now decomposed body?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok For the completely righteous, decomposition is not supposed to happen. For others, the soul is purported to reside in the Tzion, the stone marker of the departed, on that day. If you are interested in learning about this subject as taught within traditional Jewish teaching, you should look into Sefer M’avar Yabbok.

Comment: @YaacovDeane thank you. Do you have a better link to Sefer M’avar Yabbok than this: https://hebrewbooks.org/11774 ?  Where should I look in the sefer? But even so, what is the purpose of the neshomo rejoining the dead body of the righteous?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok You are certainly welcome. After looking at the link, my suggestion would be to actually purchase a new edition. They are indexed, which will help you to navigate subject. They are also retypeset with easy to read Hebrew characters. With blessings for an auspicious Lag b’Omer…